# How to push heroku app with hyper ? getting error

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, web, heroku

I tried these commands:

[image: Screenshot]

```sh
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/young-brook-98064.git'
```

Where did I made a  mistake ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Answer (score 1):

`error: src refspec main does not match any` means you don't have any commit to push.

And you don't have any commit because your first commit fails.

Your first commit fails because you don't have set `user.name`/`user.email`

If you do this operations in order (tell Git who you are, make a commit, then push), it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to push it to `master` instead of `main`:

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: This may be correct, but this would be a higher quality answer if you added more information.  How did you figure this out?